# get keycode with shiftkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get keyCode if they are pressed with shift Key,

for ex. I press a  and then b. 
 Then I want to store it in one array like this `[shiftkey,65,66]` please suggest me if this is possible or I am going wrong.

Comment: first try something then come to SO

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sanjay:

```
<input id="down" type="text"/>


var your_array = [];

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var keyPress;

  if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
    keyPress = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  }
  else if (e) {
    keyPress = e.which;
  }
    if(keyPress == '16'){
    keyPress = 'shift';
    }
  your_array.push(keyPress);
 alert(your_array);
    // returns [shift,65,66];
  return false;   // Prevents the default action
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = [];
    var wait = true;
    window.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (wait) {
            if (a[0] != e.keyCode) { a[0] = e.keyCode;  }
        }
        wait = false;
        window.addEventListener('keyup', key_up, false);
    }
    function key_up(e) {
        a[1] = e.keyCode;
        if (a[0] == a[1]) { a = []; }
        wait = true;
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', key_up, false);
        console.log(a);
        alert(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pressedKeysSeries = [];
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) { pressedKeysSeries = []; });
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && pressedKeysSeries.indexOf(e.key) === -1) {
        pressedKeysSeries.push(e.key);
    }
    console.log(pressedKeysSeries);
});
```